Using SPI with CRC and DMA on a STM32F407 what signals the end of CRC transfer?
I have 2 STM32F407 processors talking via SPI.  The slave monitors many inputs, when something of interest happens it interrupts the master which starts the SPI transfer.  This process is register based (NO HAL) and 100% driven by interrupts and DMA and everything works as it should.  The problem is when SPI CRC is added.  The Reference Manual RM0090 Rev 19 pages 891 and 892 provide CRC configuration details.  It indicates (I think) that the NSS line needs to be held low at least into the beginning of the CRC transmission. See steps 5 and 6 page 892.
If I leave the NSS line low after the DMA transfer of the data, the CRC is received and tested without any errors. All is good. If I bring the NSS line high at the end of DMA transfer I receive 0x00 for the CRC and as expected get a CRC error.
My issue is that if I leave the NSS line low to do the CRC transfer, I do not have anything to signal me when that CRC transfer is complete so that the NSS line can be raised again. I have spent several days trying to solve this but have not found any way to detect the end of CRC transfer when using DMA.
I must be missing something. Others must have this configuration working. If anyone can give me a clue as to what signal triggers the end of an SPI transfer with CRC using DMA and possibly how it should be configured, I would be most grateful.
Thanks in advance for any help.
Jim

NSS going high at end of 4 bytes of data.

NSS staying low at end of 4 bytes of data.

In the absence of any code I'd guess that this is a hardware problem. If so, this is not the place to ask. Try [electronics.se]

What are all the places where you can set the transfer length, and what are you setting it to?  Seems to me you should set it to 5 bytes everywhere.  For instance, the DMA transfer should only be finished after 5 bytes have been transferred, and you should only release NSS after the DMA transfer is done.

(But I haven't read the datasheet carefully.)

Clearly from the question it is not a hardware issue. It is a configuration issue.

David. There are 5 bytes being transferred. 4 are my data and the last is the auto calculated CRC. As best I understand it through both reading the data and reference manuals and testing is that the SPI controller is doing the CRC as each byte is being sent. The DMA controller tells the SPI controller when it is on the last byte (#4 in this case) and the SPI controller sends the CRC after the last data byte is totally sent.

I need a way to know when the CRC has been sent by the SPI controller. The SPI TXE flag seems to trigger at the end of DMA data and not the end of the CRC. I do NOT want to use a blocking timeout.

I found a solution. Spin wait for the SPI status register busy bit to go low. Not very elegant and blocking, but it works.
